# How to call a function located in your controller file in your main file JavaFXML

Tags: java, function, javafx, controller, fxml

I was wondering how I would go about calling a function that is located in the controller file in the main java file.

Right now I get an error where I call the function and it tells me "cannot find symbol"

Here is where I am calling the function in my main file.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

     timeLine2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), actionEvent -> updateStopwatch() ));
```

So there is an error where updateStopwatch() is.

Here is the function in my controller file

```
@FXML
 private void updateStopwatch(){
    elapsedTime++;
    Integer rotation = elapsedTime * 6;
    hand.setRotate(rotation);      


 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can't you just start the timeline from the controller's `initialize()` method?

Comment: can you provide the entire exception please